# How to customized advanced search in Magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1

I want to customized the advanced search in Magento 2.

When I want to go to the advanced search URL, below steps will appear:

1) An input field to enter the name of the user, then "Go to Started."
Button.

2) 1st question will appear to select an answer, then click "Next
Button".

3) 2nd question will appear to select an answer, then click "Next
Button".

4) 3rd question will appear to select an answer, then click "Next
Button".

5) finally, search button will appear and product will be searched on
click the search button.

Also, the "**Previous button**" will appear with each question.

I have created **each question as the product attribute** and add
their values.

Please suggest customized advanced search like this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jquery for displaying the form field.

for example:

check URL : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11556661/8344381

Hope, it will be helpful.